# Fetch videos from DKAssets

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `DKImagePicker` for multiple selection of images and videos. I'm fetching images but I don't get how to fetch videos?
Sharing code below of what I've tried so far.
Please guide.

```
func setImage()
{        
    let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
    pickerController.showsCancelButton = true
    pickerController.showsEmptyAlbums = false

    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        print("didSelectAssets")

        self.assets1 = assets
        print(assets.count)

        for asset in assets {
            asset.fetchImageWithSize(PHImageManagerMaximumSize, completeBlock: { image, info in
                if let img = image {
                    // let fixOrientationImage=img.fixOrientation()

                    User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryImages.addObject(img)
                    print("array after selecting images and videos", User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryImages)

                    kAppDelegate.imageSelected = true
                }
            })
        }

    }
    if(!(kAppDelegate.imageSelected))
    {
        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true)     {}
    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the videos, The DKAsset has a property isVideo. Make use of it.

```
for asset in self.assets {
  if asset.isVideo == true {
    asset.fetchAVAsset(.None, completeBlock: { video, info in

    })
  } else {
    asset.fetchImageWithSize(PHImageManagerMaximumSize, completeBlock: { image, info in
            if let img = image {
                // let fixOrientationImage=img.fixOrientation()

                User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryImages.addObject(img)
                print("array after selecting images and videos", User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryImages)

                kAppDelegate.imageSelected = true
            }
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: just sent you now

Comment: thanks that error solved will update you after completing. Thanks again

Comment: Can you guide this is what getting from fetched video,
file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0025.MOV

Comment: what do you want to do with this video?

Comment: need to convert it to nsdata for sending to server

Comment: tried this
let videoURL = User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryVideos.objectAtIndex(index) as? NSURL
                var movieData: NSData?
                do {
                    let video = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
                    print("video", video)
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: video, name: "video_path[]", fileName: strVidName, mimeType: "mp4")
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591423/how-to-convert-video-path-to-nsdata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123771/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-iphone-6).

Answer (score 0):

For videos

```
for asset in assets {
            if asset.type == .video {
                asset.fetchAVAsset { AVAsset, info in
                    
                    if let videoUrl = AVAsset as? AVURLAsset {
                        print("url: \(videoUrl.url)")
                        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: videoUrl.url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```