# How to convert video path to NSData

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata

I have used `DKImagePicker` for fetching multiple videos from gallery. Able to fetch video but not getting convert to `NSData`. And also receiving error from server.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_0040.MOV” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0040.MOV, NSUnderlyingError=0x172e5f6b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

May be not converted to `NSData` properly or may be some other issue.
what i tried so far is:

```
let videoURL = User.sharedInstance.arrRoomGalleryVideos.objectAtIndex(index) as? NSURL
            var movieData: NSData?
            do {
                let video = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
                print("video", video)
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: video, name: "video_path[]", fileName: strVidName, mimeType: "mp4")
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
```

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy file into `Documents` or any other place IMMEDIATELY when you get file path from delegate method. Because originally file was placed into private folder, which is temporary as I understand. So when your 3-rd party tool finishes processing and stores into the file - it becomes inaccessible at some point.
So after you copy it using copyItemAtPath:toPath: or something like that - you may get NSData by reading it from new path.

From DKImagePicker [git](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController) I found method: `writeAVToFile(path:presetName:completeBlock:)` which may help. Look [here](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController#exporting-to-file).

Comment: This issue coming in device only, on simulator getting this error from server

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
error Optional("The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.")

Comment: Why you are using `option: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe`? Also mime type is wrong as I know, it should be `video/mp4`, and why name is `video_path[]` ?
There is something wrong with how you pack your request, please check.

Comment: "video_path[]" this is because array is sending

Comment: and mime type is because video in iphonhe is of type .mov

Comment: please modify and post changes

Comment: mime type should be `video/mp4`, not just `mp4`

Comment: But video type is .MOV

Comment: Oh, you are right, then mime type should be `video/quicktime`.

Comment: yes, i checked it works if video is .mp4 but doesn't work when type is mov

Comment: any solution for that

Comment: Can you be more specific what is your exact problem right now? As I understand - you have no problems with accessing file right now, but some problems with uploading, right?

Comment: problem with converting .mov video file to NSData

Comment: Have you tried `let video = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL!)` without options parameter?

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257
The file “IMG_0046.MOV” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0046.MOV, NSUnderlyingError=0x17604b4c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}} here

Comment: As I wrote in my original answer - have you tried to copy file to Documents folder? Error clearly say that you do not have permission to access the file. From DKImagePicker git I found that you can call copy method for this: https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController#exporting-to-file.
Try to do request after you copy to Documents by using new path